# Thunderbird Search Results -- How to find out the folder

Tags: thunderbird

When I use the global search feature in Thunderbird, it opens up a new tab with the search results.  Often it finds what I'm looking for, but then I'm stuck when I want to know in which folder and on which account the particular message has been found.

Can I display this information somehow?  Am I just overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Thunderbird (24.5.0) has subject and location columns by default in the search results box: the latter is the folder where the message resides.

You can add other columns: although the account is not an available column, the recipient is, and this should tell you which account was used on e-mails sent directly to you, provided you have identified the the account names differently (eg **My Name (Account Abbreviation)**).

Comment: I had to switch to a "list of results" to go this way but then it worked just fine, thanks!